# Retrieve full document.referrer URL

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract the keywords from Google search engine through `document.referrer`. The full referrer URL becomes like this:

```
"https://www.google.com.pk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=LXxHVIb_JNC07Qae7oCwAg#q=stack+overflow"
```

The `document.referrer` property only gives me this:

```
"https://www.google.com.pk/?gws_rd=cr&ei=LXxHVIb_JNC07Qae7oCwAg"
```

Leaving out `#q=stack+overflow`, but I also want that part after the hash.

Any idea on how I can grab the full URL?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039306/send-a-location-hash-through-a-referrer

Comment: it explains about location.href which returns the url of the current page but i want the url of the referrer page which is google search engine in my case

Comment: in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2039410/492258) it says: `the hash portion of a URL is used on the client side only. It will never appear in server logs, requests, or as part of a REFERRER string.`

Comment: but when i try to extract it from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] in php it also gives the portion after # but not in document.referrer.But according to you it is not possible for javascript referrer to grab it